# Upload multiple images and show them in Gallery ID wise

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I need to upload multiple images for a particular `Training ID` into database and show them in Gallery ID wise. I mean if I upload 15 photos for a particular ID, I should be able to view them by clicking name of that ID.

Is there any way to accomplish this using ASP.NET or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are talking about uploading multiple images to server (web app) from client (browser).

With HTML5 you can do this thing. Check YUI uploader http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-dd.html

Mozilla Docs also has good reference to understand file upload from client to server https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications